Unable to debug Quarkus application in Eclipse
I have a restful application which I am using Quarkus for the endpoints. I am using the async versions of the libraries ( see pom excerpt ) but I am also having this problem with the synchronous load out as well. For some reason , when eclipse attaches to the debug port,  Quarkus attempts to find a file : <M2_REPO>/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus/quarkus-application.dat where M2_REPO is the path to my Maven Repository.  I am able to debug to the quarkus code to find out this is the cause so it is not an eclipse issue.  Quarkus is unable to find this file and throws a file not found exception and the debugging session ends.  What creates this file ? How can I get eclipse to host debug sessions again?
Pom excerpt:
<properties>
    <!-- ... -->
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>3.9.5</quarkus.platform.version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
            <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-container-image-docker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-mutiny</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-rest-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-health</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.smallrye.reactive</groupId>
        <artifactId>mutiny</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- ... -->
</dependencies>

What I tried:
I rebuilt my repository from scratch by deleting <M2_REPO>/repository/io  and re installing packages using mvn clean install -U . I created an empty <M2_REPO>/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus/quarkus-application.dat file but then it does not contain what quarkus needs and so it also exceptions and dies. Thinking it may be a pathing issue I also searched for quarkus-application.dat over my entire home directory and it does not exist. <M2_REPO> and the project are under my hoem directory. The exception happens in QuarkusEntryPoint.java which is part of the quarkus-bootstrap-runner package.
What I expect:
either
the file to be created and then be able to debug using eclipse
the fiel to be ignored and then be able to debug using eclipse

How are you launching your application for debug, the quarkus-tools? You might have to add in JVM args to set up a listener for debug, and connect to that as a Remote Debugging session from Eclipse.

I run quarkus from command line using 'mvn quarkus:dev' and it opens port 5005 by default and I am able to connect to it in eclipse and debug to the point where it cant open the quarkus-application.dat file .   So it  strictly is not an eclipse problem as far as I can tell .

Not sure why but upgrading to maven 3.9.7 and rebuilding causes a quarkus-application.dat file to be produced under /targets/quarkus-app/quarkus/quarkus-application.dat. And I can now debug.
